# CasperJS not following redirect to HTTPS

Tags: redirect, https, casperjs

I'm trying to use CasperJS to automate away a lot of tedious data entry. Specifically, to register a very large batch of camera equipment on the canon website.

I have code to handle form filling and have no problems navigating around webpages using CasperJS but I can't get CasperJS to navigate to the login page.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36',
    logLevel: "debug"
});

phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;

casper.start();

casper.thenOpen('https://b2cweb.usa.canon.com/b2cweb/view/myAccountHome.jsf?LOGINACTION=Y', function(response) {
require('utils').dump(response);
});

casper.run();
```

*Note: The code above dumps the header contents once it reaches the page. I have also tried different user agent strings in case Adobe actively blocks crawlers.*

The link works flawlessly in Google Chrome but CasperJS just logs the following.

> Loading resource failed with status=fail

From Google Dev Tools it appears that the link 302 redirects to

> https://b2cweb.usa.canon.com/b2cweb/view/myAccountHome.jsf?LOGINACTION=Y

Then 301 redirects to:

> https://b2cweb.usa.canon.com/b2cweb/view/login.jsf?TYPE=33554432&REALMOID=06-979697ef-63e3-49da-a97f-795f9d794fcc&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=-SM-EA3lbvOPfpMVWEZ5fDNhRBdvP75YFZ%2fmmFcIOEdxcmO9f3eSAXAISOKvl7eaVyQm&TARGET=-SM-HTTP%3a%2f%2fb2cweb%2eusa%2ecanon%2ecom%2fb2cweb%2fview%2fmyAccountHome%2ejsf%3fLOGINACTION%3dY

I'm assuming that the redirects are the cause behind why CasperJS can't fetch the login page.

Is it possible to make CasperJS follow these types of redirects? Can CasperJS be used to browse and/or login via HTTPS?

**Update:**

I'm not so sure if it's a redirect that's causing the issue.

As a workaround, I tried pre-preloading the session cookie (copied from chrome) into casperjs then navigating directly to the account page.

I also tried adding the --ignore-ssl-errors=true flag to the command with no success.

No matter what I do it returns an about:blank url.

Comment: PhantomJS has problems following redirects, you may be able to automate it with [slimerjs](http://slimerjs.org/) from casperjs: `casperjs --engine=slimerjs`.

Answer (score -1):

The following will get you to the sign in page:

```
    var casper = require("casper").create ({
    waitTimeout: 15000,
    stepTimeout: 15000,
    verbose: true,
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1400,
        height: 768
    },
    onWaitTimeout: function() {
        logConsole('Wait TimeOut Occured');
        this.capture('xWait_timeout.png');
        this.exit();
    },
    onStepTimeout: function() {
        logConsole('Step TimeOut Occured');
        this.capture('xStepTimeout.png');
        this.exit();
    }
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    logConsole('***remote message caught***: ' + msg);
});

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4');

// vars
var gUrl           = 'http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/home';

// Open URL and click sign in
casper.start(gUrl, function() {
  this.clickLabel('Sign In', 'a');
});

//Sign in page
casper.then(function () {
  //+++ ready for you to fill user information.
  this.capture('xSignIn.png'); //+++ shows you are on signin page. can remove.
});

casper.run();
```